# How to fill a string variable with a string in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a that randomly generates a string currently I have to use this simplified code to generate it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
{
    var += "bx";
}
```

which sets var to "bx" 10 times. However, is there a string function to do this for me?

Comment: Could you please post a link to that question because I couldn't find it.